# 20.04 AutoInstaller - Luks Encryption

Tags: 20.04, encryption, luks, cloud-init

Question in regards to the user-data file for autoinstall in Ubuntu 20.04.

What is the best method to luks encrypt during the autoinstall? I did a manual install and then copied the autoinstall-user-data file as my base to user-data.

However if I try to use this on a different machine I cannot get beyond this step as it errors with "matched no disk"
because of this line:

```
{ptable: gpt, serial: WDC PC SN730 SDBQNTY-512G-1001_2008A6802236, wwn: eui.001b448b46a5c0f9,
      path: /dev/nvme0n1, wipe: superblock, preserve: false, name: '', grub_device: false,
      type: disk, id: disk-nvme0n1}
```

We have multiple (3-4) different laptops in our org and it would be preferable to be able to use a single install method that would cover them all.

Comment: There's some matching logic[1] that gets used to decide where to write your disk configuration. If you can post your whole cloud-init storage configuration I can propose some changes to help diagnose. [1] https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference